# How to convert two gmpz_t to a mpq_t?

Tags: c, type-conversion, gmp

I have two integers (gmpz_t), and I need to express them as a fraction (one being the numerator, the other the denominator). The only solution I found is using `char* mpz_get_str (char *str, int base, mpz_t op)` to convert them both to `char*`, then concatenate them with a "/" inbetween, and then use  `int mpq_set_str (mpq_t rop, char *str, int base)` to put the value into a rational. But that seems like a lot of effort and I imagine there must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not convert each to `mpq_t` via `mpq_set_z`, then divide?

Comment: That should work, didn't think of it. I'll test it and if it works as expected, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: They really should provide a dedicated function for this.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Applying-Integer-Functions.html), there are functions `mpq_set_num` and `mpq_set_den` that allow you to separately set the numerator and denominator from some `mpz_t`. More generically, `mpq_numref` (resp. `mpq_denref`) lets you work on the numerator (resp. the denominator) of an `mpq_t` as if it was an `mpz_t`, so you can call `mpz_set(mpq_numref(q),z)`. To be safe, I would call [`mpq_canonicalize`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Rational-Number-Functions.html) afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, if you have `mpz_t rn, rd` (numerator, denominator), this would be my solution:

```
mpq_t ratn, ratd, t;
mpq_init(ratn);
mpq_init(ratd);
mpq_set_z(ratn, rn);
mpq_set_z(ratd, rd);
mpq_init(t);
mpq_div(t, ratn, ratd);
mpq_clear(ratn);
mpq_clear(ratd);
...
do something with t
...
mpq_clear(t);
```